# Why am I unable to access properties of `this` inside a mdDialog controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

The code is as follows:

```
function showVote(ev, poster) {
            $mdDialog.show({
                // var parentDOM = document.getElementById("poster-page");
                parent: angular.element(document.getElementById("poster-page")),
                controller: posterVoteController,
                templateUrl: 'view/poster_vote_tmpl.html',
                targetEvent: ev,
                locals: {
                    poster: poster
                }
            });
        }

function posterVoteController($scope, $mdDialog, poster) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.test = "TEST!";
}
```

And when I access it like `{{posterVoteController.test}}`, nothing appears. Only if when I write as `$scope.test = "TEST!"` and access `{{test}}` would it work.

What is the correct way to write the controller in this case? And one more question, how can I use the `controller as alias` syntax? Where do I write it?

Comment: you would need to use `controllerAs: 'posterVoteController',` in the properties of the `$mdDiaolog.show({`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@Claies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/claies) mentioned, you may use `controllerAs` syntax directly in options object for `$mdDialog.show(options)`.

The [official doc (Dialog #3)](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.0/api/service/$mdDialog) is pretty confusing where in its comment it says:

> Here we used ng-controller="GreetingController as vm" and $scope.vm === controller instance=""

but not using it in the sample at all. (For `angular-material@1.0.3`).

---

Here are 2 working examples you may use:

### Explicitly `controllerAs` syntax

```
angular.module('poster', []);

angular
    .module('poster')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

angular
    .module('poster')
    .controller('PostVoteController', PostVoteController);

// This is the main controller for you app where you will bind showVote to
funciton MainController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.showVote = showVote;

    // ...

    function showVote(ev, poster) {
        $mdDialog.show({        

            // ...

            controller: 'PosterVoteController',

            // This is where the magic happens
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'view/poster_vote_tmpl.html',
            targetEvent: ev,
            locals: {
                poster: poster
            }

            // ...
        });
    }

    // ...    
}

// This is the controller used for your $mdDialog
function PosterVoteController($scope, poster) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.test = "TEST!";
}
```

### Combined `as` syntax in controller

```
angular.module('poster', []);

angular
    .module('poster')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

angular
    .module('poster')
    .controller('PostVoteController', PostVoteController);

// This is the main controller for you app where you will bind showVote to
funciton MainController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.showVote = showVote;

    // ...

    function showVote(ev, poster) {
        $mdDialog.show({        

            // ...

            // Just like in Angular 1.3, you can use controllerAs syntax like this
            controller: 'PosterVoteController as vm',            
            templateUrl: 'view/poster_vote_tmpl.html',
            targetEvent: ev,
            locals: {
                poster: poster
            }

            // ...
        });
    }

    // ...    
}

// This is the controller used for your $mdDialog
function PosterVoteController($scope, poster) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.test = "TEST!";
}
```

Two ways are exactly the same. It's just a choice of coding style.

Reference: [Official Document for ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a ng module like this:

```
var app = angular.module('demo-app',[]);
```

you can define controller like this:

```
app.controller('posterVoteController',($scope, $mdDialog, poster) {
    $scope.test = "TEST!";  //use $scope is right way
}
```

And use it like :

```
           $mdDialog.show({
                // var parentDOM = document.getElementById("poster-page");
                parent: angular.element(document.getElementById("poster-page")),
                controller: 'posterVoteController',
                templateUrl: 'view/poster_vote_tmpl.html',
                targetEvent: ev,
                locals: {
                    poster: poster
                }
            });
```